# Function keys get stuck (stay pressed)

Tags: ui-automation, autoit

I made <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> start a function using AutoIt, but using this the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys get stuck held down. Inserting `{CTRL up}` and `{SHIFT up}` has no effect. Why does this happen?

My AutoIt script :

```
$dll = DllOpen("C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll")
Global Const $keys[8] = [0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0x5b, 0x5c]
;0xa0   LSHIFT
;0xa1   RSHIFT
;0xa2   LCTRL
;0xa3   RCTRL
;0xa4   LALT
;0xa5   RALT
;0x5b   LWIN
;0x5c   RWIN

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "stop")
HotKeySet("^X", test)
Opt("SendKeyDelay", 0)
Opt("SendKeyDownDelay", 0)

While True
    Sleep(500)
WEnd

Func test()
    Send("The control and shift keys are going to be stuck down at the end of this.")
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Send("PlaceHolder,")
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Send("PlaceHolder")
    Send("{TAB}")
    Send("{HOME}")
    Send("{LCTRL up}")
    Send("{RCTRL up}")
    Send("{LSHIFT up}")
    Send("{RSHIFT up}")

    Call("UnstickKeys")
EndFunc

Func UnstickKeys()
    For $vkvalue In $keys
        DllCall($dll, "int", "keybd_event", "int", $vkvalue, "int", 0, "long", 2, "long", 0) ;Release each key
    Next
EndFunc

Func stop()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>stop the script
```

Comment: not sure about Autoit, but from what i know it acts like VBA\VB6 , this means 

While True
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

is your potential problem. endless loops are never a good thing. specially ones that hold the thread.

Comment: @Stavm Controlled endless loops are great things...how else would I keep my script alive? 

I've always used an endless loop with AutoIT to keep the script running, otherwise it runs once. This endless loop stops as soon as I hit the pause/break key.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your test function below. This solution has a problem because to run the function again you will need to let go of shift and ctrl and repress them. You can remove the dll call from your code. I also disabled the ^X hotkey while the function is being called. It's just safer that way.

```
Func test()
  Hotkeyset("^X")
  Send("The control and shift keys are going to be stuck down at the end of this.")
  Send("{ENTER}")
  Send("{ENTER}")
  Send("PlaceHolder,")
  Send("{ENTER}")
  Send("PlaceHolder")
  Send("{TAB}")
  Send("{HOME}")

  send("{CTRLDOWN}")
  send("{CTRLUP}")
  send("{SHIFTDOWN}")
  send("{SHIFTUP}")
  Hotkeyset("^X", "test")
EndFunc
```